# removing domain from admin to use it in workspace for organization creation (associate organization from managed acct into gmail account)

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I need to remove my domain that is listed under  admin.google.com in account --> domains --> manage domains  to be able to use that domain in cloud identity or work space.

It attached my domain to a new admin(ex: user@mydomain.com) account when I was trying to make an organization through my gmail account as my project is under gmail account as a "no organization" setup.

So now I need to remove the domain so I can attach it  to a workspace so I can create the organization

But I am not seeing the remove button when I go to admin --> account --> domains --> manage domains .

I am following this document - https://support.google.com/a/answer/183028

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didnt need to remove my domain from my admin account, what I did instead is used my organization from admin account into my gmail account. Initially when it created the admin account (ex: user@mydomain.com) , it already created a workspace account and organization. All I needed to do is associate this organization with my gmail account.

- create a group in admin account and provide  organization administrator permission
- Add a user in that group  and associate  the gmail email  address that is used to create the project
- Make the user as owner
- Go back to your google cloud console using your gmail account.  You should see organization from your admin account and you should be able to choose that organization for whatever purpose you need to. I chose it to migrate my compute engine project from my gmail account to managed admin account